# Unable to execute SPARQL query in java (exception in QueryExecution .execSelect() method)

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I am trying to execute the SPARQL query in JAVA but getting the exception in .execSelect() method

I am using Apache Jena to execute the query. The dependencies I added in pom.xml are

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
  <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
  <type>pom</type>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
  <artifactId>jena-text</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The code (this query is perfectly running on [Virtuoso SparQL Query editor](https://dbpedia.org/sparql)) I am trying is

```
String queryStr = "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" + 
            "PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>\n" + 
            "SELECT ?uri ?label \n" + 
            "    WHERE {?uri  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?categories .\n" + 
            "?categories rdfs:label ?label\n" + 
            "    FILTER (?uri = dbr:Holy_Roman_Empire || ?uri = dbr:Part-of-speech_tagging || ?uri = dbr:Alt-Berlin || ?uri = dbr:Named-entity_recognition)\n" + 
            "    FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en' || lang(?label) = 'de')\n" + 
            "}\n" + 
            "ORDER BY DESC(?uri)";

        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryStr); 
        QueryExecution qExe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService( "http://dbpedia.org", query );
        ResultSet results = qExe.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query) ;
```

The exception I am getting in qExe.execSelect(); is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.format(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;

Am I missing some dependency?

Comment: 1.) you should use version `3.10.0` - don't know why you want to use a version being several years old. 2.) It's mostly because you have some other dependency to `httpcomponents`, which doesn't contain the method. Check you dependencies with `mvn dependency:tree`